# Port mapping doesn't work for one service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my compose file ubuntu-zabbix.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  zbx-backend:
    image: zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:ubuntu-3.0-latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_SERVER_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_USER: zabbix
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: zabbix
      MYSQL_DATABASE: zabbix
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 10051:10051

  zbx-frontend:
    image: zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:ubuntu-3.0-latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_SERVER_HOST: db
      ZBX_SERVER_HOST: zbx-backend
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_USER: zabbix
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: zabbix
      MYSQL_DATABASE: zabbix
    depends_on:
      - db
      - zbx-backend
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Run it by command

```
docker-compose -f ubuntu-zabbix.yml up
```

OS Version/build:
Ubuntu 16.04.4/Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24

Problem is on zbx-backend. Docker should setting up port forward :10051, what is not done. That can be seen in debug output.

In debug output(dockerd --debug) is not any port mapping of :10051 nor any iptables setting on zbx-backend also nothing like 'programming external connectivity on endpoint zabbix-docker_zbx-backend_1' https://pastebin.com/raw/8LvZy3dc

I can connect to port directly to container IP, so there should not be problem with port itself:

```
root@prod1:~/zabbix-docker# telnet 172.18.0.4 10051
Trying 172.18.0.5...
Connected to 172.18.0.5.
Escape character is '^]'.

root@prod1:~/zabbix-docker# telnet 127.0.0.1 10051
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Any idea how can I get zbx-backend iptables/port mapping working up? Thanks

Comment: i tested your config and it is working OK. The port is mapped and working. But in the backend it seems there is no app listening on port 10051...

Answer (score 1):

Problem appears to be in configuration update. On the new host everything is fine, I see in debug log setting iptables for zbx-backend. On the old host I do not see e.g. changed service name in debug log but it is changed in stdout of command docker-compose. Not sure issue is related to the docker or docker-compose.